# Shortcut or utility program to temporarily disable subpixel font rendering when making a screen capture / screenshot

Tags: fonts, screenshot, screen-capture

Anyone know a utility program or a shortcut that disable subpixel font rendering when capturing a screen?

I'm capturing for print output, so it's better to have regular font smoothing than subpixel.

Comment: What OS?????????????????????

Comment: sorry, ms windows 7